# Community/Experience Cloud login options - email or username?

Tags: lightning-community, login, community-cloud, username, experience-cloud

Sometimes people remember their username and passwords, but sometimes they don't.

The default login page for a Community (or the newly branded Experience) requires a Username & Password

[image: default login]

The default/auto-created "Login Discovery" Page ([documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_login_discovery_create_discovery.htm)) offers the ability for a person to enter their email address (or phone number) and receive a verification code to enter.

[image: login discovery]

I'd like to keep the default username/password screen but also offer the "Login Discovery" screen if people can't remember their username.

**Do I need to create two custom login screens -> one with the default username/password and also a hyperlink for "Forgot Your Username?" which would link to the second page which would basically be the "Login Discovery"?** Seems like overkill as the functionality is default there, but can't find a simpler solution yet so asking here...